# [Cpack Stuck In Preinstall]add_custom_target command use cpack for rpm components, stuck in preinstall stage

Tags: c, linux, cmake, centos7, cpack

cmake --version

cmake version 3.16.2

centos7 information:

Linux wxt 3.10.0-1160.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Oct 19 16:18:59 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

I want to pack a RPM package, There are some files to install in 2 compnents. When I don't use add_custom_target for cpack command, after I execute the camke .. && make command, I manually execute the command: cpack -G RPM --config ./CPackConfig.cmake, there is no problem for pack all files.
I just want to pack files automatically, so I add a target in my CMakeLists.txt in below picture:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMJPS.png)

Then I execute the camke .. && make command, I expect it can finish compiling and package all my files. But what happens actually is when the command: "cpack -G RPM --config ./CPackConfig.cmake" is executed, it will stucked in preinstall stage. there are just 4 files to install, And files in the installation directory are constantly created and deleted. The stuck picture is below:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfa2w.png)

Even if I execute command "cpack -G RPM --config ./CPackConfig.cmake" manually, it also stuck in preinstall stage.
I found that if I change the file in my build directory: "build/CMakeFiles/A_pkg.dir/build.make", just change the line in below picture for other command such as: "mkdir 123", then I execute command "cpack -G RPM --config ./CPackConfig.cmake" manually, it works!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qIWnZ.png)

I know that change CPACK_CMAKE_GENERATOR to other value for example "Ninja", it can bypass phase preinstall, but I want to know why custom target cause preinstall stuck, and how can I solve it by set CPACK_CMAKE_GENERATOR as "Unix Makefiles", My code is in the GitHub cmake's issue attachment in below link, you can download it in the attachment. Please tell me how to solve the packaging problem in my code, My code is extremely simple!

Link:

https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/23529

Download attachment In the link above:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQxCM.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Here we discourage **images** which represents *textual* information - e.g. the code or the output. Instead, copy paste the text directly into the question post (and format it accordingly). Also, while it is allowed to give links to external cites, we expect the question post itself to contain all relevant information. You may find useful to read [ask].

Comment: Including `CPack` module will provide a `package` target for you, so to build packages just run `make package` or equivalent...